# list index out of range _ UNET

Tags: indexing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, semantic-segmentation

I would be grateful if you can help me solve the problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tifffile as tiff
import os
    
rows = 3
cols = 4
axes=[]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=[10,10])
i=["/images/1","/masks/1","/images/2","/masks/2"]
i=i+["/images/3","/masks/3","/images/4","/masks/4"]
p=1
m=0
for a in range(rows*cols):
  if i[m].find("masks")!=-1:
    b = plt.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/PFE_MOHTICH/dataset/data/test{}.png".format(str(i[m])))
  else:
    b = tiff.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/PFE_MOHTICH/dataset/data/test{}.tiff".format(str(i[m])))
  m=m+1
  axes.append( fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, a+1) )
  plt.imshow(b)
  plt.savefig("ex_val.png",cmap='binary_r')
  fig.tight_layout()    
  plt.show()
```

The line which results in an error

```
(if i[m].find("masks")!=-1) :
```

the error message:

```
list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's hard to see in this. Your `for` loop

```
for a in range(rows*cols): #rows*cols = (3*4) = 12
# In this loop you update m every iteration
  m = m+1
```

so your m goes from `0` to `11` while your `i` has only `8` elements. 
Like what is it that you can't see/get?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't pay attention to this